# Определить сколько чисел входят в интервал и записать ответ в массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, циклы, numpy

Есть массив `а` состоящий из 10 случайных  чисел от 0 до 1. Нужно сделать 10 равных  интервалов и узнать сколько чисел попадут на каждый интервал и запписать ответы в массив `b`.

Нужно заменить часть кода, где `if`:

```
import random
import numpy
mas=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
p=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for i in range(10):
  mas[i]=random.random()
  print(mas[i])
  if mas[i] > 0 and mas[i] < 0.1:
    p[0]=p[0]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.1 and mas[i] < 0.2:
    p[1]=p[1]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.2 and mas[i] < 0.3:
    p[2]=p[2]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.3 and mas[i] < 0.4:
    p[3]=p[3]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.4 and mas[i] < 0.5:
    p[4]=p[4]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.5 and mas[i] < 0.6:
    p[5]=p[5]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.6 and mas[i] < 0.7:
    p[6]=p[6]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.7 and mas[i] < 0.8:
    p[7]=p[7]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.8 and mas[i] < 0.9:
    p[8]=p[8]+1
  if mas[i] > 0.9 and mas[i] < 1:
    p[9]=p[9]+1
print()
print('среднее 
значение:',numpy.mean(mas))
print()
for i in range(10):
  print(p[i])
```

Comment: Приведите пример случайного чисел от 0 до 1.

Comment: @S.Nick речь же не о натуральных числах

Comment: @S.Nick 0.31476 0.02947 и тд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas
import numpy as np   #  pip install numpy

np.random.seed(123)
# создаем Pandas Series из 10-ти случайных чисел
m = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
print(m)

# корзины / интервалы
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)

res = m.groupby(pd.cut(m, bins=bins)).count()
```

Результат:

```
In [42]: m
Out[42]:
0    0.696469
1    0.286139
2    0.226851
3    0.551315
4    0.719469
5    0.423106
6    0.980764
7    0.684830
8    0.480932
9    0.392118
dtype: float64

In [43]: res
Out[43]:
(0.0, 0.1]    0
(0.1, 0.2]    0
(0.2, 0.3]    2
(0.3, 0.4]    1
(0.4, 0.5]    2
(0.5, 0.6]    1
(0.6, 0.7]    2
(0.7, 0.8]    1
(0.8, 0.9]    0
(0.9, 1.0]    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Умножьте эти случайные числа на 10, возьмите целую часть от результата, и добавьте единицу к соответствующему счётчику в массиве

```
p[int(mas[i]*10)] += 1
```